# Erro ao abrir arquivo php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, xampp

Quando vou abrir meu arquivo php pelo XAMPP aparece o seguinte erro
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\compraquindex\cadastrar.php on line 44"

Não consegui identificar onde errei :(

```html
<?php
    require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
    $u = new usuario;

?>

<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title>Tela de Cadastro</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilocad.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="corpo-form">
        <h1>Cadastre-se para começar a economizar!</h1>
        <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome" maxlength="30">
        <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="email" maxlength="40">
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="senha" maxlength="15">
        <input type="password" name="confSenha" placeholder="confirmar senha" maxlength="15">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastro">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nome']))
{
    $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
    $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
    $confirmarsenha = addslashes($_POST['confSenha']);
    
    if(!empty($nome) && !empty($nome) && !empty($senha) && !empty($confirmarsenha))
    {
        $u->conectar("projeto_login","localhost","root","");
        if($u->msgErro == "")
        {
            if($senha == $confirmarsenha)
            {
                if($u->cadastrar($nome,$email,$senha));
                {
                    echo "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Email já cadastrado";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Senhas não correspondem!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
        }
    }else
    {
        echo "Preencha todos os Campos!";
    }
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe, tire o `;` da linha `if($u->cadastrar($nome,$email,$senha));`

Answer (score 1):

corrija a linha de número 40 retirando o ';' do final.

Segue correção do seu código:

```
   <?php
        require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
        $u = new usuario;

    ?>

    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <title>Tela de Cadastro</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilocad.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="corpo-form">
            <h1>Cadastre-se para começar a economizar!</h1>
            <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome" maxlength="30">
            <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="email" maxlength="40">
            <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="senha" maxlength="15">
            <input type="password" name="confSenha" placeholder="confirmar senha" maxlength="15">
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastro">
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['nome']))
    {
        $nome = addslashes($_POST['nome']);
        $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
        $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
        $confirmarsenha = addslashes($_POST['confSenha']);

        if(!empty($nome) && !empty($nome) && !empty($senha) && !empty($confirmarsenha))
        {
            $u->conectar("projeto_login","localhost","root","");
            if($u->msgErro == "")
            {
                if($senha == $confirmarsenha)
                {
                    if($u->cadastrar($nome,$email,$senha))
                {
                    echo "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Email já cadastrado";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Senhas não correspondem!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
        }
    }else
    {
        echo "Preencha todos os Campos!";
    }
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Corrijo um erro aparece outro, acho que cometi algum erro muito grave nesse código.

Comment: e só vc copiar e colar o código acima que resolve seu problema.